# How to create a spinning icon in android

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I'm trying to implement this common spinning icon I see in many android apps (Gmail below). It is mostly used when refreshing list views. Does anyone know what it is called and how it can be about implemented in a list view?

[image: Spinner icon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a progress bar! :)

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/myRotatingProgressBarBar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

Setting `indeterminate="true"` makes it a rotating circle rather than a classic progress bar.

There are several different styles you can use. Play around with them to find the one you like :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: would it be possible to set it as false when the list loads?

Comment: yep: myRotatingProgressBarBar.setIndeterminate(indeterminate); However, you'd probably just want to make it go away by setting setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 2):

It is ProgressBar
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

You just need to setup in your xml file like this:

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ProgressBar` android have various styled `ProgressBar`. [More info click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)